# how to Hash an already existing password?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

After testing and ensuring my Send_email function authenticates successfully using the hardcoded user and password in the SQL Table, I am now trying to Hash the password.

the way my columns are set up is something like this:

### variable | value

password | someP@ssword

the columns are varchar both, with the value column being 1000 length (is that too much? i set it to that much cause i read that sha 512 requires a lot of length or something, and seen examples using 1000 at least so went with that)

I am using this query to hash,

```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] (value)
    VALUES(HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'someP@ssword'))
```

but it generates a nonbinary hash, which i am suspecting is why i am receiving this error of email authentication failed because it probably cant decipher the nonbinary password characters. but the problem is i have other values in the value column, so i can't convert the whole column to varbinary.

### so is there a way to hash the password that is hardcoded or i have to insert it as hash? or is there a way i can convert just that particular field/cell without having to alter the rest of the design of the value column so it wont affect other values in there as well? or am i supposed to create a completely separate column for password and set it to binary?

EDIT: I have to pass the password in this email function call for authentication:

```
Send-EMail -EmailFrom $From_Email -SendTo $To_Email -Body $Email_Body -Subject $Job_Success_Email_Subject -Username $SmtpUser -Password $SmtpPassword
```

but Von in the comment said i can't pass the hashed password in there as credential. then that means i have to keep it nonhashed in the table? i thought hashing would work perfectly in this situation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have been confused by the irrelevant discussion in the comments above.

First of all: hashed password would not work in your `Send-EMail` function as the function has no way of "unhashing" said password. Read this introduction to [Hashing vs Encryption](https://www.securityinnovationeurope.com/blog/page/whats-the-difference-between-hashing-and-encrypting).

If you want to secure your password and be able to retrieve original value you will need to **encrypt** it. The topic of encryption is quite large and way outside the scope of what can be written in SO. I will provide a few links for you to read:

http://www.manjuke.com/2018/03/data-encryption-in-sql-server-using-t.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-and-database-encryption-keys-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Encryption by pass phrase would be the simplest to implement but also weakest as anyone reading the code of an SP will find out the pass phrase and therefore can decrypt data. **Note** that pass phrase itself can be passed into `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` as a parameter, allowing you to store it (securely) elsewhere outside the database i.e. you don't have to hard code in your SP code. You will need to implement pass phrase storage method yourself if you decide to go this way.

Encryption using keys and certificates offers a very secure method but requires some time to set-up in addition to **very carefully** backing up your keys. If you loose your keys your data is gone i.e. you can never decrypt it.

As far as storing binary data in `varchar` column goes - easy, here is an example:

```
DECLARE @BinValue VARBINARY( 500 ) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'someP@ssword')
DECLARE @StringBinValue VARCHAR( 500 ) = CONVERT( VARCHAR( 500 ), @BinValue, 1 )
SELECT @BinValue, @StringBinValue, CONVERT( VARBINARY( 500 ), @StringBinValue, 1 ) AS BackToString
```

I have used your original `HASHBYTES` function as an example but you will need to change it to an encryption function.

Hope this clarifies things for you.

Comment: yes thank you. I am writing a script and was saving some common variables in a text file in key-value pair. Then I took it a step further and made a table instead holding those variables. I have to now secure the password in the table, so I thought hashing was the way to go. I didnt know hashed values cannot be passed. Oh well lester learned! So hashed values can only be useful in scenarios of ”comparison? Such as a user inputting the value and the hash value being compared to it, right? As far as encryption, I dont like the idea of keys and certs, this is supposed to be very simple: /

Comment: I may end up using the first method u mentioned (pass by phrase). So from what I understand, the encrypted value still has to be decrypted right?

Comment: I have updated my answer to add a note about `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`

Comment: so I read the first blog. From what I saw is the value has to be included in the decrypt function? DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Pa$$W0rd4EnCRyPt10n')? Hmm that's kinda useless then :/ because this means I have to hardcode the password inside the script....I was hoping the function would just be DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('$SmtpPassword')

Comment: @Cataster - it would be useless not to require a pass phrase to decrypt, as anyone can call this function to decrypt any value. I suggest you spend a few hours reading into what encryption is and how it works, at least at a general level. Almost everything uses it in some shape or form nowadays.

Comment: Dang, I guess I'm gonna I have to use Chef to store password there and retrieve it from chef....I was hoping a simple encryption method or hashing would do the trick here instead of resorting to chef